# java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected node Pythonid; nodes=[org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal, org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Anybody knows what is the workaround for the following issue?

I could not find anything useful other than: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164202

The issue occurred after Android Studio asked me to install some plug ins:

Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected node Pythonid; nodes=[org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal, org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX, org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle, org.jetbrains.plugins.github, org.jetbrains.java.decompiler, org.jetbrains.idea.maven, org.jetbrains.android, org.intellij.intelliLang, org.intellij.groovy, org.editorconfig.editorconfigjetbrains, hg4idea, com.millennialmedia.intellibot, com.jivesoftware.robot.intellij.plugin, com.intellij.ui-designer-new, com.intellij.tasks, com.intellij.properties, com.intellij.modules.xml, com.intellij.modules.xdebugger, com.intellij.modules.vcs, com.intellij.modules.python, com.intellij.modules.platform, com.intellij.modules.lang, com.intellij.modules.json, com.intellij.modules.java, com.intellij.modules.androidstudio, com.intellij.modules.all, com.intellij.java-i18n, com.intellij.copyright, com.intellij, com.google.gct.testing, com.google.gct.login, com.google.gct, amailp.intellij.robot, TestNG-J, Subversion, JUnit, Git4Idea, Coverage, CVS]
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.buildOuts(GraphGenerator.java:55)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.<init>(GraphGenerator.java:36)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.create(GraphGenerator.java:40)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.createPluginIdGraph(PluginManagerCore.java:543)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1126)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.loadApplicationComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ex.ApplicationManagerEx.createApplication(ApplicationManagerEx.java:45)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.<init>(IdeaApplication.java:112)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 16):

**Short answer:**

Linux (and most likely Windows too):

`echo Pythonid >> ~/.<JetBrainsProduct>/config/disabled_plugins.txt`

OS X:

`echo Pythonid >> ~/Library/Preferences/<JetBrainsProduct>/config/disabled_plugins.txt`

**Long answer:**

I ran into a smiliar issue with IntelliJ 15. Though not the same, Android Studio is based on IntelliJ and the fix should be similar:

- Find the applications' configuration folder (for IntelliJ15 that is `~/.IntelliJIdea15/config`, Android Studio is something like `~/.AndroidStudio/` (on Linux and Windows, on OS X look into `~/Library/Preferences/<JetBrainsProduct>/`)
- open the file `disabled_plugins.txt` and append a line like `Pythonid`
- start the IDE again

Official answer to this problem can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147244 (they do provide a different solution)

Comment: Please be aware that for newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA (e.g. 15), the correct path is `~/.<JetBrainsProduct>/config/disabled_plugins.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, I think it should always be in the `config` subfolder as described in the long answer. i'll update it accordingly.

Comment: The disabled_plugins.txt mentioned above is located in ~/Library/Preferences/JetBrainsProduct/disabled_plugins.text

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround. Remove Android Studio installation by following steps below:

```
Delete the android-studio folder;
Delete the sdk folder if it is in not inside the android-studio directory;

rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio, which contains config and system;
rm -rf ~/.android;
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-android-studio.desktop, if you created a shortcut using Configure->Create Desktop Entry.
```

Sometimes the icon launcher can be in one of the following locations too:

```
/usr/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
If your launcher file is in any of the first two directories, you will require root permissions to remove it.
```